# How to vertically align elements in a table element?

Tags: html, reactjs, html-table, react-bootstrap

I have some issues with my tables. I create two tables, one under the other and I want to center elements but I'm having issues with his part. My elements aren't vertically aligned and also they aren't really centered as you can see on the picture below.

[image]

The code is the following one:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
import Table from 'react-bootstrap/Table';
<Table>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td style={{width:"33%", textAlign: 'center', wordWrap: 'break-word', overflowWrap: 'break-word', width:"33%"}}>
         <p> Negative = 0, Neutral = 1, Positive = 2.</p>
         </td>
         <td style={{width:"33%"}}>
            <p style={{display: 'flex',  justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}}> Filter the prediction </p>
            <input
            style={{display: 'flex',  justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}}
            className="form-control input-sm"
            name="filter"
            type="text"
            maxLength="1"
            pattern="0|1|2"
            />
         </td>
         <td style={{textAlign: 'center', wordWrap: 'break-word', overflowWrap: 'break-word', width:"33%"}}>
         <center>
            <p style={{color:'#FFA500', fontSize:20}}> In order to download the CSV file, you must validate each highlighted line</p>
         </center>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</Table>
<Table striped bordered hover className='dataTable'>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>#</th>
         <th>Text</th>
         <th>PyFeel</th>
         <th style={{whiteSpace:'nowrap'}}>
            Google CNL
         </th>
         <th>Cancellation</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</Table>
```

(I don't know how to add the `react-bootstrap` to the snippet)

How can I align and center my first table elements ?

Comment: Okay so I already removed the `<center>` and it fixed one problems

Comment: before posting it as an answer and just to be sure, is this what you are looking for? https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-elgamal-d3b5c

Comment: @Apostolos yes :)

Comment: ok posting it as an answer then :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So what you need to do at first is to define in your `td` a `verticalAlign: 'top'` property in order for all tds to be aligned.

Also, if you use different font at one `td` a small difference will be shown (it will be displayed some pixels lower than the other tds if font is bigger) so you should use same font for all `td`.

Check this [sandbox](http://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-elgamal-d3b5c)